# apache - can't download files with extended ascii characters

Tags: download, debian, apache2.4, extended-ascii

Recently upgraded apache on debian. It seems new version is giving 400 error when trying to download files having extended ASCII char in filename.

Old apache version -

> [25/Apr/2018:03:34:34 +0200] "GET
>   /etmain/\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f.pk3
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 42631 "ET://xxxxx:27960" "ID_DOWNLOAD/2.0
>   libcurl/7.12.2"

New apache version -

> [24/Apr/2018:23:08:52 -0400] "GET
>   /etmain/\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f\x7f.pk3
>   HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "-"

Also in new version it seems it's not registering referral in access logs.

New apache version info -

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
Server built:   2018-03-31T08:47:16
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:68
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     worker
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
```

Old version info -

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Sep 15 2016 20:44:43
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:37
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
```

Any help appreciated to resolve the issue.

Comment: Nothing in the errorlog? Shouldn't those bytes have been URL-encoded?

Comment: Nothing in error log somehow. I pulled that up from access log. Can you please elaborate by "Shouldn't those bytes have been URL-encoded?"  - It's game file addon with extended ASCII char set.

Comment: client's bugged. If the URL contains bytes outside of 7-bit ascii printables, they must be URL encoded. URL encoding e.g. %20 for space or %7f for your repeated character.

Comment: Just an update  -  I reverted back to old version and it worked. How can be client bugged? it was working before and only after apache update to new version it was broken.

Comment: Because the new Apache version more strictly enforces the specifications about valid characters in URLs and headers.

Comment: I even tried to use HttpProtocolOptions unsafe in apache2.conf but still it doesn't work. Any idea how to make it work on new versions?